# Nginx - removing Last_Modified header also removes CORS headers?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to remove the Last_Modified headers from Nginx responses.

I've read that this can be achieved by this line in the config:

```
 add_header Last-Modified '';
```

This works, however for some reason our CORS Access-Control headers are then no longer sent.  I'm assuming this might be a bug (we are on v1.2.6), but would like others' opinion.

**Why is this happening? and What can I do to remove Last-Modified, but keep the Access-Control headers?**

Our config file looks like this:

```
http {

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
        root xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

        expires 1y;
        log_not_found off;

        add_header Last-Modified '';
    }
}
```

Comment: RTFM. _There could be several add_header directives. These directives are inherited from the previous level if and only if there are no add_header directives defined on the current level._

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The nginx `add_header` directive is a bit... special, and its behaviour when being inherited from a less-specific scope is a trap for the unwary.  As the documentation states:

> There could be several add_header directives. These directives are inherited from the previous level if and only if there are no add_header directives defined on the current level.

This means that, once you specify *any* `add_header` directives in a given configuration block, you must also specify any `add_header` directives from less-specific scopes which you want to retain.